# Window.AttachDevTools() не находит

Tags: c#, avalonia

Как сказано вот здесь - https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/getting-started/developer-tools , чтобы включить отладчик, необходимо вызвать AttachDevTools(). Но метода не существует, причём я даже добавил в зависимости Avalonia.Diagnostics, как советовали здесь:

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3634

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/7824

Кто подскажет как правильно пользоваться Avalonia.Diagnostics, но не вот это https://docs.avaloniaui.net/api/untitled/avalonia-ui-framework-27 простоперечисление, желательно чтобы был хотя бы 1 пример?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Внимательно прочитайте предоставленную вами ссылку, там сказано, что "этот код автоматически генерируется в DEBUG режиме", то есть вам по сути ничего не надо делать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да, вы правы, спасибо. Я задал вопрос из-за того, что первый раз у меня почему-то не сработало F12